ImportError: symbol not found in flat namespace '_ERR_error_string' when using sqlcipher3 on macOS
I'm trying to use sqlcipher3 on my mac. I've installed SQLCipher using Homebrew and the sqlcipher3 Python package via pip. However, when I attempt to import sqlcipher3 using the following code:
from sqlcipher3 import dbapi2
I encounter the following error:
ImportError: dlopen(/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.10/lib/python3.10/site-packages/sqlcipher3-0.5.2-py3.10-macosx-10.9-universal2.egg/sqlcipher3/_sqlite3.cpython-310-darwin.so, 0x0002): symbol not found in flat namespace '_ERR_error_string' 
Here are the steps I've followed so far:
Installed SQLCipher using Homebrew:
brew install sqlcipher
Installed sqlcipher3 using pip:
pip install sqlcipher3
Set environment variables to include SQLCipher paths:
export C_INCLUDE_PATH="$(brew --prefix sqlcipher)/include" export LIBRARY_PATH="$(brew --prefix sqlcipher)/lib" 
Reinstalled sqlcipher3:
pip install --no-cache-dir --force-reinstall sqlcipher3
Despite these steps, I still receive the ImportError mentioned above.
